# How to locate dynamic downloaded filename using Selenium + Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to locate the chrome downloaded filename using locator. I need to get the filename to proceed further on automation to verify the content.

Element HTML:

```
<a is="action-link" id="file-link" focus-row-control="" focus-type="fileLink" tabindex="0" role="link" href="https://energyfuture.cgi.com/pasdemo/operations/QueryDisplay!displayQuery.action?QUERY_TIMESTAMP=1614571607262" class="">Facility Balance_1614571607828.xlsx</a>
```

Here the numbers of filename are dynamic, but the prefix Facility Balance will be constant.

code I have tried:

```
driver.navigate().to("chrome://downloads/");
String Text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='file-link']")).getText();
```

OR

```
String AttributeData = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Facility Balance')]")).getAttribute("linkText");
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters

```
.getAttribute("linkText");
```

will not work because your target node does not contain an attribute called `linkText`.

The second point,

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='file-link']")
```

might not work if you have multiple elements with the same ID on the page (this include popups). Consider refining your xpath to be more explicit.  For example, `By.xpath("//a[@id='file-link' and ...]")` where the `...` are additional conditions that will refine your search to find only one.

Out of curiosity, did you try your Xpath directly in the browser developer's tools? Before you attempt to code things like this, you should always attempt to evaluate your XPath expressions to make sure that 1) they are accurate and 2) they are not ambiguous. Unfortunately, given the amount of information posted, this is the extent of the help I can give you.

Comment: I have only 1 single download file in the chrome instance it runs.. So it would be distinct for sure. I will try my xpath in the developer's tool. Thanks.

Comment: @Sneha let me know how it goes so I could help you further.